# Message.Create is not a function sequelize cli

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have installed mysql sequelize in my project then I creadted Message Model using sequelize command  which create model and migration file .I also given the db credentials in config.json file.Now I am trying to insert record in my db but getting this error here is my model file

---

> DO i need to make db connection explicitly or it auto picks the
>   credential from config.json file to make connection ?

---

**models/messages.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
var Messages = sequelize.define('Messages', {
 room: DataTypes.STRING,
nickname: DataTypes.STRING,
message: DataTypes.STRING,
receiver: DataTypes.STRING
 }, {
classMethods: {
  associate: function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  }
}
});
 return Messages;
};
```

here is config.json file 
**config/config.json**

```
{
"development": {
"username": "root",
"password": "asad",
"database": "chat",
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"dialect": "mysql"
},
"test": {
"username": "root",
"password": null,
"database": "database_test",
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"dialect": "mysql"
 },
"production": {
"username": "root",
"password": null,
"database": "database_production",
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"dialect": "mysql"
 }
}
```

and here is my server file to save record
**app.js file**

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();
  var app = express();
 var server = require('http').createServer(app);
 server.listen(4000);
 var Messages=require('../models/Messages.js');

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var a =req.body;

 Messages.create(a).then(() => {

  console.log('success ')

})
 })
```

Comment: what is your error message

Comment: Message.create is not a function @VikashDahiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sequelize connection instance and export it, please use config according to your environment

```
const sql = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
  host: config.host,
  dialect: config.dialect,
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },

});
module.export = sql;
```

In your app.js import sql instance and connect your db before starting your server.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var sql = require(./sql);
sql.authenticate().then(()=>{
   server.listen(4000);
});

var Messages= sql.import('../models/Messages.js');

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var a =req.body;

 Messages.create(a).then(() => {

  console.log('success ')

})
})
```

Comment: @Asad please tell me if have any other doubt

Comment: I have to make db concetion explicitly or cli auto picks credential from config,json file @Vikash

Comment: you have to make it explicitly and then when you start ur server in app.js u shld call sql.authenticate()

Comment: it saying sql not defined

Comment: Actually i was thinking cli does it itself like migration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157987/discussion-between-asad-and-vikash-dahiya).